# Avoid bold font in acronym list

Tags: acro

Using the package `acro`, I would like to avoid the short form of my acronyms to appear in bold in the printed acronym list. When defining the short form, I could specify that I want it in `normalfont`, but this keeps the short form to appear in italics whe I am in such an environment. Is there another way?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{abc}{short=\normalfont{ABC},long=Alphabetical}

\begin{document}
    \printacronyms
    
    This works fine: \acf{abc}.
    
    \textit{However, when writing in italics, I want the short form to be in italics, too: \acf{abc}---this fails.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should prefer

```
\DeclareAcronym{abc}{short=ABC,long=Alphabetical,short-format=\normalfont}
```

to apply formatting to a specific acronym.

But that doesn't help here, the bold is hard-coded through the `description` environment. You could (in a group as necessary) apply a formatting to all acronyms

```
\acsetup{format/short=\normalfont,format/replace=false}
\printacronyms
```

where `format/replace` is needed to ensure `\normalfont` is applied even if an acronym has its own `short-format` which would otherwise override any global `format/short`.

Or you could modify the `description` environment, which is easiest with [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)

```
\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont}
\printacronyms
```

The effects of which you can see with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{abc}{short=ABC,long=Alphabetical}
\DeclareAcronym{abd}{short=ABD,long=Not alphabetical,short-format=\itshape}

\begin{document}
\acf{abc} \acf{abd}
\textit{\acf{abc} \acf{abd}}
\printacronyms

{\acsetup{format/short=\normalfont}
\printacronyms}

{\acsetup{format/short=\normalfont,format/replace=false}
\printacronyms}

{\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont}
\printacronyms}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled code]